# Divide ndarray by its own column indices

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have this numpy ndarray:

```
myarray = np.array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
                     [ 1.,  2.,  3.]],
                     [[ 4.,  5.,  6.],
                      [ 4.,  5.,  6.]]])
```

Is there any vector operation I can to do divide each value in the ndarray with (the value's own column index + 1)?

Result I want is

```
[[[1., 1., 1.],
 [1., 1., 1.]],
 [[4., 2.5, 2.],
 [4., 2.5, 2.]]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for vectorized divisions across all columns, like so -

```
myarray/(np.arange(myarray.shape[-1])+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [244]: myarray
Out[244]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.]],

       [[ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.]]])

In [245]: myarray/(np.arange(myarray.shape[-1])+1)
Out[245]: 
array([[[ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ],
        [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ]],

       [[ 4. ,  2.5,  2. ],
        [ 4. ,  2.5,  2. ]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

For the more general case, you can divide by (one-based) indices along a certain axis with:

```
axis = 1
myarray / (1 + np.indices(myarray.shape)[axis])
```